# How to access Angular 8 website without using base-href folder name in browser

Tags: angular8, href, production-environment

I have angular 8 website which I build for production using following command:-

> ng build --prod  --configuration=production --base-href /eportal/*

I have created a folder "eportal" in hosting site and uploaded all components in the folder. It all worked fine and I can browse to the site using following url:-

> [www.abc.org/eportal/login](http://www.abc.org/eportal/login)

Is there any method or any command available in Angular 8 where I can keep my components in "eportal" folder in hosting site but access in this way(removing folder name):-

> [www.abc.org/login](http://www.abc.org/login)

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all the —prod flag is an alias to —configuration=production. Please take advantage of this

Coming to the question in particular, use the following command

```
ng build —prod
```

There should be assets generated in your **dist/[app-name]/** folder.

In your hosting site, instead of uploading those assets in the folder you created upload them outside.

ie. You would have uploaded your assets in public_html/eportal instead of that upload them in public_html directly.

Comment: @simpleuser My Pleasure